# Reduced Echelon form of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am asked to find the reduced echelon form of a matrix $A = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    6 & 7 \\
    17 & x\\
    \end{pmatrix}
$, if $x \in \mathbb{R}.$

I am not so sure as to what to do with x. Should I just treat it as any number, or divide my solutions in different cases depending on x?
Eitherway, I tried doing the following: $$\begin{pmatrix} 6 & 7 \\ 17 & x\\ \end{pmatrix} \Rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} 17 & x \\ 6 & 7 \end{pmatrix} \Rightarrow (ρ_2 \leftarrow ρ_2 - \frac{6ρ_1}{17}) \begin{pmatrix} 17 & x \\ 0 & \frac{119-6x}{17} \\ \end{pmatrix} \Rightarrow (ρ1 \leftarrow *(\frac{1}{17})) \begin{pmatrix} 1 & \frac{x}{17} \\ 0 & \frac{119-6x}{17} \end{pmatrix}
$$Is this correct, or do I need another approach? I appreciate the help!

Comment: You were only asked to put this in row-echelon form, not in reduced row-echelon form, so it is fine.  You could also have just said that the RREF is either $\begin{pmatrix}1&\frac{7}{6}\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ in the case that $x=17\cdot\frac{7}{6}$ (*noting that the second row would just be a multiple of the first*) or $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ otherwise since the rows would have been linearly independent.

Comment: My bad, it needs reduced. I completely forgot to add it. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: For reduced, you do need to note that you can not divide by zero which forces you to break into cases based on whether the expression you try to divide by involving $x$ was zero, which leads to what I described above.

Comment: Do you mind explaining what do you mean by saying linearly independent? And why would that cause the matrix to be $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: A collection of vectors $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_k$ are said to be linearly independent if the only choice of scalars $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_k$ that make $\alpha_1v_1+\alpha_2v_2+\dots+\alpha_kv_k=0$ is when $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=\dots=0$.  For two vectors, even more simply two nonzero vectors are linearly independent iff they are not scalar multiples of one another.  [The invertible matrix theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InvertibleMatrixTheorem.html) can be used here to note that a square matrix whose rows are linearly independent necessarily row reduces to the identity.

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate the help so much! Conclusing, in my responce other than the division with zero, I will also have to include everything you mentioned in your first comment right? Again, thank you very much and sorry for bothering you.